# How do you compile an executable file in scheme?

Tags: compilation, scheme, executable, racket

I want to make an executable file for the following code.
This is scheme written in Dr.racket.
How would this be done?
It would be best if it can be stand-alone and if I can open it in on iOS and Windows.
Thank you very much for your time!

```
#lang racket

(require racket/gui/base)
(require compiler/embed)


; Make a frame by instantiating the frame% class
(define frame (new frame% [label "GUI"]
                   [width 200]
                   [height 200]))


; Make a static text message in the frame
(define msg (new message% [parent frame]
                          [label "This box is empty"]))


; Show the frame by calling its show method
(send frame show #t)
```

Comment: Have you already looked at the following?  http://docs.racket-lang.org/drracket/create-exe.html

Comment: I looked at (http://docs.racket-lang.org/raco/exe.html) and (http://download.plt-scheme.org/doc/4.2.3/html/mzc/exe.html). They are both hard to understand.

Comment: I've read this now, and it make sense. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As pointed by @dyoo, in Racket you can create an executable from the menu and (depending on the selected/available options) pack the required libraries; read the [instructions](http://docs.racket-lang.org/drracket/create-exe.html). Also you can create executables for other platforms using command line [tools](http://docs.racket-lang.org/raco/exe.html).

For a more general and portable solution, consider compiling the code to C first and then compile from C to a native executable; take a look at the [raco](http://download.racket-lang.org/docs/5.1/html/raco/index.html) tool (section 9.3), or look at a Scheme implementation designed for easily compiling to C, such as [Chicken Scheme](http://www.call-cc.org/) or [Gambit Scheme](http://gambitscheme.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page).

Getting the code to run under iOS might be trickier, a quick search returned a [Gambit REPL](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/gambit-repl/id434534076?mt=8) for iOS, give it a try but I don't think there's support for compiling to native Objective-C code, although Gambit [claims](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambit_%28Scheme_implementation%29#C.2B.2B_and_Objective-C_integration) to have "full integration support for C++ and Objective-C compilers", you'll have to experiment with it a bit.

Finally, notice that GUI code specific to Racket (like the one in the question) will almost certainly be non-portable across different Scheme implementations/platforms...